# Unable to remove boot options on Asus motherboard

Tags: motherboard, cmos, factory-defaults

I have an Asus H81M-K motherboard that boots into its UEFI BIOS Utility. It seems that my old boot options are still showing up in the utility even though I have tried the following:

1. Removing all hard disk, thumbdrives, any bootable
2. Resetting the mobo to optimised default settings
3. Remove the cmos battery for a minute
4. Reset CMOS with the pin trigger

After searching online, the understanding I got is that these data are stored in the NVRAM.

Does anyone know how should I go about clearing these boot priorities? And why didn’t a factory reset (load optimized defaults) doesn’t really clean this up?

Comment: When you "reset CMOS", does it successfully reset _other_ firmware settings?

Comment: @grawity, the time did reset and so did the other original settings.. just the boot priority list refuses to go.

Answer (score -1):

There is a utility called easyUEFI. Download the trial version, open it and delete the ghost boot options.

Comment: While this may be true, the answer is too terse.  Please edit it to provide enough information so that readers can judge that it is true, without trying it.  Add a reference if necessary.